# how to stop update poco class when edmx file update

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-4, asp.net-4.5

I have created one project with asp.net 4.5 and created entity classes with the use of "EF 4.x POCP Entity Generator"

Now the problem is i have put some variables in one of the POCO class but as soon as i update the edmx file then those manually added variables been removed it self so if any one has idea to stop updating POCO classes when edmx update then let me know

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is the normal behavior. POCOs are generated each time you update your EDMX.
But as POCOs are partial classes it's pretty easay to customize them.
Have a look this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd456844%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) where you'll find a way to customize your POCOs `without having to worry about losing your customization when the generated files are refreshed`.